# How can I tell if my cats are related?

Tags: cats, anatomy, genetics

I got my cats two years ago from the rescue centre and very little was known about them; the rescue centre says they were both two-year-olds when I got them, but one "seems" to be older than the other (a few specks of grey hair and a less smooth coat - unsure if this means anything, though).

They have extremely similar features so I'm wondering how to tell if they're sisters or even potentially mother and daughter?

[image] [image]

Comment: Maybe a service that somewhere like here would provide? https://www.vgl.ucdavis.edu/services/cat/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are siblings, but to be 100% sure you need a DNA test; for me, they look like they are from the same litter (same age and same color patterns).

They most likely have the same mother and father, as you got them from the same place and at the same time.

The rescue center did say they where two years old when you got them and they look to me like they are of the same age (it looks like it is too little difference in their age to be mother and her kitten, judging from the pictures from the rescue). If your rescue center was right about the age of them, they are siblings.

And the small difference in their size has continued, judging from upper picture, taken about two years after you got them.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your answer, someone told me the patterns do not mean anything in terms of sibling-ness but I feel like these are far too similar not to be related. Cheers :)

Comment: Indeed, the shape of color patches in cats is not genetic, but developmental, as in the conditions of the womb determine where the color patches are expressed.